# How to Call StoredProcedure using Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

Hi I want to Call a stored procedure in db2 using hibernate.Can you please give complete example without using CallableStatement.

Comment: Hi Stijn,I have googled for this,actually am unable to insert the record using procedure and i tried to using in out parameter even am getting exception like could not read **.hbm file.

Answer (score 2):

Directly from the Hibernate reference documentation: [Using stored procedures for querying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/querysql.html#sp_query).